# How to rewrite this datepicker code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this [library](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I have some JS code for initialization:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        maskInput: true,
        pickTime: false
    });
    $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        maskInput: true,
        pickTime: false
    });
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pickDate: false,
        maskInput: true,
        pickSeconds: false,
        pick12HourFormat: true
    });
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pickDate: false,
        maskInput: true,
        pickSeconds: false,
        pick12HourFormat: true    
    });
});
```

I don't like it because if I have 10 more elements I will have 50 more strings of repeated code, so the thing I wanna do is this:

```
var DateTimePicker = {
    constructor: function(id, language, maskInput,pickTime,pickSeconds,pick12HourFormat){
        this.language = language;
        this.maskInput = maskInput;
        this.pickTime = pickTime;
        this.pickSeconds = pickSeconds;
        this.pick12HourFormat = pick12HourFormat;
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    },
    initialization: function() {
        document.getElementById(this.id).datetimepicker({
            language: this.language,
            maskInput: this.maskInput,
            pickTime: this.pickTime,
            pickSeconds: this.pickSeconds,
            pick12HourFormat: this.pick12HourFormat
        });
    }

};
var firstDatepicker, secondDatepicker, firstTimepicker, secondTimepicker;
firstDatepicker = Object.create(DateTimePicker).constructor('#datetimepicker2','en', true, false, false, false);
secondDatepicker = Object.create(DateTimePicker).constructor('#datetimepicker3','en', true, false, false, false);
firstTimepicker = Object.create(DateTimePicker).constructor('#datetimepicker4','en', true, true, false, true);
secondTimepicker = Object.create(DateTimePicker).constructor('#datetimepicker5','en', true, true, false, true);

firstDatepicker.initialization();
secondDatepicker.initialization();
firstTimepicker.initialization();
secondTimepicker.initialization();
```

This gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datetimepicker' of null

So I think I am trying to do something really weird. I suspect that `datetimepicker` is an object which I am trying to manipulate incorrectly. Could you please help me with this, I am just learning JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because you're calling `datetimepicker()` on a DOMElement. Use `$(this.id).datetimepicker()` instead.

That being said, I would argue that your 'simplified' version is actually more complex and difficult to maintain.

If you look at the settings you're using you only really have two different settings; those with `pickSeconds` and `pick12HourFormat` and those without. As such you could just use two classes by placing the relevant one on the required datepicker. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.simple-datepicker').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        maskInput: true,
        pickTime: false
    });

    $('.adv-datepicker').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pickDate: false,
        maskInput: true,
        pickSeconds: false,
        pick12HourFormat: true    
    });
});
```

Obviously the class names can be adjusted as you require, but you can now use the above code for an infinite number of datepickers in your page, so long as they have the right class added to them.

Comment: Yeah you are right,i already did it,but i am wondering what i did wrong in my code?Could you please give me a little feedback?

Comment: Your error is because you're calling `datetimepicker()` on a DOMElement. Use `$(this.id).datetimepicker()`

Comment: Wow,yeah you were right,now i have another issue,settings its not applied to my inputs and all of them are calendars,but i get right properties here:
console.log(this.pickTime);//false,false,true,true